# Loading 2 yaml's to same parameter namespace

Tags: ros, yaml, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to load 2 sets of parameters from 2 different yamls to the same namespace from a launch file, like this:

YAML1:

```
- id: foo1
  waypoints:
    - type: foo1
```

YAML2:

```
- id: foo2
  waypoints:
    - type: foo2
```

Launch file:

```
    <node name="foo" pkg="foo"
          type="foo" required="true">

          <!-- Common config, applicable to all robot types -->
          <rosparam file="$(arg common_maintenance_config)" command="load" ns="maintenance_motions"/>
          <!-- Configuration specific to this robot -->
          <rosparam file="$(arg robot_specific_maintenance_config)" command="load" ns="maintenance_motions"/>
   </node>
```

Seems pretty straight-forward, right? In practice, I find that the second set of parameters overwrites the first. So if I do `rosparam get /maintenance_motions` the result is:

```
- id: foo2
  waypoints:
    - type: foo2
```

So the second yaml overwrote the first one. What is the least janky workaround? I've already tried loading all parameters in the global namespace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415922/loading-2-yaml%27s-to-same-parameter-namespace/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2023-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2023-05-28**:
Kinda-related question:  https://answers.ros.org/question/199608/roslaunch-order-of-rosparams/

Possible answer involving a Python script here:  https://answers.ros.org/question/361582/ros-launch-get-param-in-launch-file-to-append-to-param-from-config-file/?answer=397388#post-id-397388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up writing a simple Python script which concatenates the two yaml files together into one yaml file, then loads that one. Like this:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-merge-two-files-into-a-third-file/

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2023-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1